# In Parshas Barashis (4:21) Noah's wife Namah was born before 130 AM. How could she have children at 1,160 yrs? How can she live longer than 1,000 yrs?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, chumash

We find from The Simple reading of Chumash/Rashi Parshas Barashis:
Perek 4 Pusuk 21 "..Tubal-cain's sister was Naamah" Rashi "Naamah: She was Noah's wife"
On Pasuk 25 "And Adam knew his wife again..she named him Seth.." Rashi says (paraphrasing Medrish Rabba and Eruvin 18b) "Lemech came to Adam to tell his wives to live with with him again (since they separated from him in Pasuk 23 see Rashi there) they told Adam take back your own wife first, and therefore it says And Adam knew his wife again" Perek 5 Pasuk 3 says "And Adam lived to 130 years and he begot...Seth" (Rashi: 130: until then he has separated from his wife)
Chapter 5 Pasuk 32 says "And Noah was 500 years old, and Noah begot Shem, Cham and Yafes."
We also see that The Flood occurred in year 1,656 (That can be worked out by adding up the age that the generations of Seth to Noah were born to their fathers- **Or** just look at any Chumash with a "Timeline" Artscroll or otherwise)

We learned a few things from here, #1 Seth is younger than Naammah since she was born before him in the year 130 of creation ( I don't know for certain if its in Erivin 18b and Ber. Rabba that Rahi quoted, or Bal Haturim or elesewere, that Zela and Ada had 2 children so that they were no longer obligated
in the Mitzva of Peru U'rivu like Adam who had Kayin and Hevel)
#2 Naamah was Noah's wife and they had had children when Noah was 500 years old.
#3 The Flood occurred in year 1,656.

It seems fairly obvious therefore that Naamah lived at least until 1,657 yrs. Old (assuming she died as soon as they got off the Ark)

My 1st question is I had always thought that when Hashem sad whoever eats from the Tree of knowledge will die on that day it meant 1,000 years (like Tehillim "To Me a thousand years is like a day") he gave 70 years to Adam as Rashi brings down, Mesushelash lived closer to 1,000, however none of these 10 Generations lived longer than a 1000 yrs.

My second question is how can Naama began having children at 1,160 years old?

It could be that I am wrong and that althought the Pasuk says "Naamah was the brother of Tuvel-Cian" perhaps it was not in that order and she was born much later, and maybe that's what Rashi is explaining  when he says "Naamah: She was Noah's wife" i.e. that's why she's mentioned here even though she wasn't born yet.
I could also be that Adam did have children who surpassed the age of 1,000 (although the ones whose Ages were listed did not)
**However** even then you would hard-pressed to say that she was under a thousand when she died or under a thousand when she gave birth to her children.

Comment: I don't think I have ever understood the order of the verses in Beresheet to mean that all of the descendants of Kayin listed were born before Shet was the born. When considering the ages that the descendants of Shet had children, it seems strange to think that the descendants of Kayin would be any different. Moreover, do we know how old Adam was when Kayin killed Hevel? I mean, even if we did consider your idea that the 130 years encompassed the prior verses, I'm not entirely certain the math would work.

Comment: I upvoted you because you are the first person to come up with my favorite question. I have never heard anyone ask it before. I have always used this at the table and prove that there is hope for all singles if a fifteen hundred year old girl can catch a 600 year old guy ;) People really think hard once they hear the math etc. This is a good question. TY

Comment: @Harel13 the problem comes from taking together all the midrashim (quoted by Rashi) which seem to imply that Tuval-Kayin was born before Shet was born to Adam

Comment: @JoelK oh, I see now.

Comment: To add to your question, in the מדרש כג , ה the יפה תואר uses your question as to explain why this is an opinion in the medrash that another נעמה was the wife of noach.

Comment: Rashi in iyov 29 18 brings that there is a bird called chol, that didn't eat from the עץ הדעת, hence never died. Rather, every 1000 years it would return to its youth. Perhaps if this is true for נעמה, giving birth at such an age is more understandable.